# Using the "Header and Footer Scripts" Wordpress Plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

So I'm working on a Wordpress site for a client, and he wants a div to be clickable.  Elementor is making that a pain, so I'm trying to use Javascript to make that happen.  The issue is I can't get the click event listener to work, and I can't figure out why.  Code is posted.  Here's the [page](https://buildinguppeople.net/writings/) I'm working on.  The plugin that I'm using is [Header and Footer Scripts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/header-and-footer-scripts/).

The oddest thing to me is that alert functions still work, but nothing else.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("academicsbox").addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.location.href = "https://buildinguppeople.net/academics/";
}); 
</script>
```

I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious, but I appreciate the help.  Thanks!

Comment: I think you are selecting the wrong element. Put your id="academicsbox" identifier in the <div class="elementor-widget-wrap"> div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `window.open` instead and make sure your academicsbox identifier is in the correct div.

```
document.getElementById("academicsbox").addEventListener("click", function(){
    window.open('https://buildinguppeople.net/academics/', "_self");
    console.log("working");
});
```

Working example: https://codepen.io/fraggley/pen/VwvXpQg